# ASP.NET Website & Entity Framework in seperate thread / multiple threads

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, iis

we have an asp.net website which uses the Entity Framework 4 as ORM Mapper to a SQL Server.

The database functionality is located in an project that is compiled to an DLL, so it's not directly included in the web site.

We had several performance issues, so we are searching for a "magic switch" that decreases the time for materialization and other weaknesses.

I have a theoretical question:

Is it possible to run the entity framework project (the dll) in another thread then the website? I think of splitting the database work from the IIS worker thread. Or is it even possible to run the database worker (the dll) multiple times? (We are not using caching since it is not built in and we did not find an elegent solution.)

Thanks in advance

**Edit: thanks for the answers, but I think my point was not clear enough.**

I'm looking for a method to run the DLL of the Database functionality (that is used in nearly every .aspx(.vb) file) in a seperated thread. I have no idea how to run the dll at another thread, because it is just imported and not "started".

**Would it be a solution to run a new thread before creating the context and create the context in the new thread?? The context is kept as long as the current httpcontext in our solution.**

Comment: Have you implemented any caching?

Comment: As stated in the question: No Caching.

Answer (score 2):

Threading is almost never a "magic switch".  Apps typically have to be written to be multi-threaded, and trying to force a single-threaded app to be multi-threaded is a recipe for catastrophe.

I'm not even sure what you hope to gain by being multi-threaded.  The objects still have to be materialized on a single thread, whether it's your main thread or a worker thread it still takes the same amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Profiling is a necessary step in the process of using EF for anything but trivial queries.

Answer (score 0):

( restriction in amount of links for new users - therefore multipart answer )

### Performance (in general)

some guideance

1. [MSDN Performance Considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx)
2. [P&P Chapter 6 — Improving ASP.NET Performance](http://Improving%20.NET%20Application%20Performance%20and%20Scalability)

1 - Wich in turn links to "Exploring the Performance of the ADO.NET Entity Framework"
that explains several options like compiled queries, lazy loading, no tracking etc.

2 - General aproaches like multitude of built in caching options (perhaps? that is in some degree elegant enough) and ways of working with threads.

Comment: thanks, but as I mentioned in my post, I've read everything about performance considerations, but I'm searching for a threading solution.

Answer (score 0):

### ASP.NET

Maximizing Performance with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET Web Application
- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/maximizing-performance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-web-application

explains several options and ways of analyzing the generated queries

Entity Framework FAQ - http://www.ef-faq.org/objectcontext.html
see 3.2. What is the recommendation for running a **multithreaded** application on the Entity Framework? Is the Entity Framework thread-safe? :

> The Entity Framework, like most of the rest of the .NET framework, is by and large NOT thread-safe. So if you want to interact with the Entity Framework or your entity classes from multiple threads, then you must pay careful attention to concurrency issues. One simple model that works for some cases is for each thread to maintain its own context so that no locking is required. This means, of course, that the interactions between the threads must be quite limited (for instance you can't pass an entity from one thread to another without being very careful), but you can do some useful things in spite of these restriction. You could, for example, retrieve data on one thread by using MergeOption.NoTracking, and then divide the data into groups and hand it off to other threads that attach the entities to their own thread context, make updates, and then save.
>
> You could also have one thread for all of your database interactions and send entities over to other threads for processing and back to the database thread for a save. In this scenario, make sure the entities are detached from the context any time they are updated on the other threads or else you will end up with race conditions as the state manager works to keep track of all those changes and therefore is implicitly used from multiple threads simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

### For your theoretical question(s)

1. possible to run the entity framework project (the dll) in another thread then the website

yes : by handling query materilization in another project like in a N-tier application and sending the filled objects from project B to project A; more info

N-tier application - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321569.aspx

Building N-Tier Apps with EF4 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335715.aspx

2 run the database worker (the dll) multiple times
"yes", same answer as 1.

//Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider replacing EF with a Micro-ORM such as Dapper-Dot-Net, which is much faster. You can find plenty of info on Dapper right on this site.

Comment: I've read a lot about dapper-dot-net, but the project contains more then hundred pages, so replacing is not an option.